# Play is Resetting currentTime to the End of the Audio after "ended" Event Triggered

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to build a HTML5 canvas app with Javascript for Samsung Smart TV 5.0.

One of the issues I'm having with audio is looping a song. The best looking way to do that seems to be to call
`mySound.addEventListener("ended", function(){ this.currentTime = 0; this.play(); }, false);`
However this sets `currentTime` to 0 and `paused` to false, but when checking moments after this `currentTime` is equal to the sound duration again but `paused` remains false and no sound plays.

Does anyone know why it's skipping the `currentTime` to the end or while it's still remaining `paused`, or a workaround to get a sound clip to loop in Samsung Smart TVs?

Comment: Does this work in other browsers?

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and it works fine but haven't checked any others

Comment: No need to set `currentTime` to initial position before `play()` in `ended` handler. According to spec "If the playback has ended and the direction of playback is forwards, and the media element does not have a current media controller, seek to the earliest possible position of the media resource."

Comment: If I take out the `currentTime` reset and just leave in `play()` I still have the same problem of the `currentTime` being set to the sound duration and it being unpaused after the even function, but thanks anyway Igor